# Is there a way to combine on-premise DNS + Azure-provided name resolution?

Tags: azure, dns

So I have a VNet in Azure, which needs to resolve names to servers back in the on-premise environment. I can set the VNet to use custom DNS servers and specify our current DNS boxes Ips.

However, whenever I do that I seem to lose the ability to resolve any Azure-based names for VMs hosted in the Azure VNet.

So I added 168.63.129.16 to the list of custom DNS servers, but not much luck. I am thinking of adding 168.63.129.16 to the existing on-premise DNS boxes so it can be used to forward Azure based request to it.

Bottom line: I need to resolve names back to on-premise but keep Azure name resolution for all VMs within the VNet. I'll be also running AAD Domain Services on the same VNet (so my custom DNS server list wil need to add the 2 extra AAD DS IPs for it,

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS is not able to resolve your Azure-based servers because it doesn't know about them, and if you're moving to us AAD DS then this will get worse. You will need to either join these machines to the domain (to auto-register with DNS) or manually add entries for them.

You won't be able to split your DNS between two different systems.